# Benefits of Rooting Your Android Device?

Tags: android, root

I hope I'm allowed to ask this non-programming related question here on StackOverflow. If not, I'm sorry...

Anyways, I bought a Samsung Galaxy S2 (running android 2.3.3) and have been reading up on rooting the device. What benefits do you get if you root your android device?

I'm quite in the dark about this still...

Comment: You might be better off posting this on [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: They could have - and SHOULD have - just migrated your question to either the android.stackexchange.com site, or possibly serverfault, or even superuser communities - all part of stackexchange. It's poor practice, in my view, to shut people down like this just because you can. Therefore, my upvote to you, Dean.

Comment: @Relborg +1 Not a non technical question. Programming is may be next step of what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to alter any system files, use themes, change boot images, delete annoying stock apps, such as Sprint's NFL Mobile live and Nascar Sprint Cup Mobile, and other various native applications that might drive you crazy (Footprints, Voice Dialer, etc).

There is plenty of information on the web on [how to accomplish this](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=how%20to%20remove%20stock%20apps%20on%20rooted%20android), but our favorite way is by using Titanium Backup and freezing/deleting the apps from there (root required, of course).

On most rooted Android devices, you can back up your entire system to an SD card, much in the same way you can image a hard drive. This is great if you’d like to try a new ROM, as you can back up your phone, wipe it completely, flash the new ROM, and if you don’t like it, just restore from your backup to get your device back to exactly how it was before you wiped it.

Read the complete post [Rooting Explained + Top 5 Benefits Of Rooting Your Android Phone](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/04/15/rooting-explained-top-5-benefits-of-rooting-your-android-phone/)